# histogram: printing group labels

Tags: r, label, grouping, histogram

I am using the following histogram command to visualize the features of a labeled dataset that has binary labels (0 or 1).

```
require(lattice)
data <- data.frame(num_child=1:10,label=rep(0:1,each=5))
histogram( ~ data$num_child | data$label ,xlab="Number of children")
```

I get a pair of histogram plots, as expected, with x-axis labeled as "Number of children" and y-axis labeled as "Percent of Total". However, the labels on top of both the plots are "data$label" rather than the value of the group label. The histogram command takes a xlab, and ylab as parameter, but does not seem to have a  parameter for the group label. How can I get the group label (i.e. "0" and "1") to be printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the easiest solution is to change your grouping to a factor:

```
histogram( ~ data$num_child | as.factor(data$label),xlab="Number of children")
```

[image]